# Is there a way to define CSS only for particular wrapper?

Tags: css

What I mean: for example I have a webpage, and a div that contains an application. Page has its own styles, but I want that application has its own style (for example twitter bootstrap styles). So is there a way to define CSS only for concrete wrapper, so that these styles for application cannot influence style of the page itself.

Sure we can always write kind of `#wrapper .btn { // style }`, but same twitter bootstrap has 100KB of styles so it would be a bit complicated to manage all the styles. It would be perfect if there was a construction similar to:

```
#wrapper {
     .btn { //style }
     .btn-group { // style }
}
```

which is equivalent to

```
#wrapper .btn { // style }
#wrapper .btn-group { // style }
```

I hope there is solution in CSS. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Twitter Botstrap uses less css http://lesscss.org/ which lets you do exactly what you mentioned:

```
#wrapper {
     .btn { //style }
     .btn-group { // style }
}
```

It is written as such, and then compiled into traditional css.  Depending on which framework/language you are using (.net, php) there are plugins specific to them.  We are using dot.less, along with bootstrap, it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Not with plain CSS.  You need to use a CSS pre-processor.  There are a handful of them, and they all support this style of nesting.

Here are a few of the most popular ones:

- Less http://lesscss.org/
- Sass http://sass-lang.com/
- Stylus http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/

---

There is also [scoped](http://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/) styles, but browse support is very poor at the moment.

Comment: thank you just found some info on less. is it actually cross-browser?

Comment: Ideally, with a CSS preprocessor you would compile your CSS before serving it to your visitors.  Compiling turns your LESS/SASS/Stylus into regular CSS, so there is no differentiation there in terms of browser support.

Comment: @Jack is right. Cross browser support doesn't matter with any of these. The markup you write is not what the browser sees.